# Python iperf module

Tags: python, iperf

I am looking for a cross-platform [iperf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf) client module for Python 2.7.

Please note that it must be freely usable in a commercial environment, and, hopefully, have good documentation.

Comment: Hm, a bit broad, isn't it? Not being familiar with *iperf* I cannot tell for sure, though. Any specific features you need?

Comment: Nope, not broad at all. I need a 100% port of full iperf functionality - as a Python module. Originally, I almost didn't have the second sentence & was going to repalec by "shortest valid question ever?@ ;)

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iperflexer/0.1.4 Maybe?

Comment: "This is a program to extract bandwidths and data transfers from iperf output", so it doesn't run iperf, just parses the output. Nvm, I have already coded both, but +1 for a useful module, which should help others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform all of the functionality of iperf with [scapy](https://github.com/secdev/scapy), *(and a lot more),* just don't let your companies IT network & security team know that you are using it they will throw a fit at what it can do.

- Create & send any packet, literally **any!**
- Receive traffic
- Time monitoring, etc
- Cross Platform
- The documentation is reasonably good for such a huge capability
- There are python 2 (the original) and python 3 versions but be sure to ask the author of the one that you are using any questions
- It is GPL so you should be able to **use** it in any environment but you may not be able to link it in or distribute it in a commercial package without applying GPL to that package.

Comment: Well, you know my IT department from other posts ;-)    I wil accep tthis as the answer, since it will help others in future. And then I will slink off and code `result = subprocess.check_output(iperfCommand, shell=True)` and keep my job